# How to close or delete my question (having an open bounty)

Tags: support, bounty

I have posted a question on Stack Overflow and the question contains some security information. Earlier the question did not contain the security information, but some people ask me to edit the question and provide the original key and password to reproduce the problem.

So far the question did not get any answer and I need to delete the question, as I have been asked to do that. If I simply do an edit, the change will be logged. What I should do?

Comment: Even if you DO manage to get it deleted it will STILL be visible to users with >10k rep. If you accidentally disclosed keys/passwords then you need to **change those credentials now**. Even if the delete actually removed the question this is still the internet. Once something is put on it there's no sure way to be sure it's completely gone. Consider the credentials you posted compromised, even if they're no longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

That is where the delete/edit tabs are located.

Comment: I am not able to delete it , It is saying question with open bounties can not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If your question not got any answers, then you can delete it via the delete option under the question itself. If you've got some answers, then you will have to flag your question to the moderator and ask him/her to delete it for you :)

Comment: I am not able to delete it , It is saying question with open bounties can not be deleted.

Comment: @Krushna - flag it for mod's attention. :)

Comment: I have flag it for mod's attention and request for a delete. Within what time the questions will be deleted ?

Comment: @Krushna - Not sure about that. The mod will act ASAP. :)